# name or formal description for the shape of a Pac-Man board

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm looking for a name for the (finite, boundless, impossible) shape created by taking a square and wrapping it so that the opposite edges are coterminous (I think that's the correct usage, it's been a while).

Effectively, this is the shape formed by the Pac-Man board, where you exit the right side of the square, and enter the left.  If the idea were expanded, you would find that all four corners exist in the same place.

Is there a name or formal way to describe such a shape (in plain language, not formulas)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, check out a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus). Visualize taking a square and identifying opposite edges: when the top and the bottom are joined, we obtain a cylinder with each open end being the right and left edges of the square. Joining these together creates a bagel shape (or at least the surface of a bagel), which we refer to as a torus.

EDIT: For Pac-Man specifically, I believe just the right and left edges are identified, so we would have a cylinder, not a torus.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it's a really good answer, but I am wondering if it's precisely correct.  The map is topologically equivalent to a torus.  But so too are a cube and sphere topologically equivalent, yet we have different names for them.

Comment: Since we are considering the rectangular Pac-Man board, you can think of it as a "flat cylinder". See the link for "flat torus", but consider only the first identification, and not the second. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus